# Can we restrict to install .apk files in our device?

Tags: android

I am new to android application development.

I developed some android applications and i install the .apk files in client devices,these are working properly.

But my requirement is ,i have to make the client device ,to support for install the .apk file from my company only.If the client is try to install any outside .apk file,then it has to rise an error.

please help me to go forward.

thank you,
bye.

Comment: what handle do you have on the actual device ?

Comment: please specify how you solved it to help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save all the device ID into an xml file and bundle it with your application when application starts just get Device id and compare it with the list you have ,if the id match then start the application or show error

you cannot block other users to block installation but I think they wont be able to use the app or even open the application if you follow above procedure

Answer (score 1):

I guess its only possible, if u make changes in Android OS Source itself, there should be some java file, i guess this [one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) which takes care of installation/uninstallation, blocking non market apps. just make a clear about it. Without which its not possible mostly.

Comment: The apps which is installed from my company only ,not other Apps which are from market or any other company.

Comment: Ya. Meant that only. There should be something in android OS to take care of installations, there you could take care of this scenario i guess.